# NSLayoutConstraint, change constant Animation form the origin, Not what I have set

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation

I want to add a sheet to the KeyWindow(  `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication ].delegate window ]` ), with animation when user taps the avatar.

I want the sheet appears straight downToUp , not from the origin ( the left and bottom endpoint), by changing the constraint's constant.
The issue sometimes happens, sometime it behaves as expected.

I guess the coordinator-layout matters.

[image: my Question Image]

**Here is my code:**  Create and show.

```
@implementation ZBPhotoSheetView

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib ];
    self.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor ] colorWithAlphaComponent: 0.3 ];
    //self.vesselViewBottomConstraint.constant = -150; // add it or not ,don't like it matters.
}



+ (ZBPhotoSheetView *)createZhePhotoSheetView
{
    ZBPhotoSheetView * zheSheetView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle ] loadNibNamed:@"ZBPhotoSheetView" owner: nil options: nil ] firstObject ];
    return zheSheetView;
}


- (void)showZhePhotoSheetView{
    if (!_sheetIsShowing){
        [[[UIApplication sharedApplication ].delegate window ] addSubview: self ];
        self.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen ].bounds;
        _sheetIsShowing = YES;

        [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.3f delay:0.f options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
            self.vesselViewBottomConstraint.constant = 0;
           // [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints ]; // add it or not ,don't like it matters.
            [self layoutIfNeeded];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
    }
}
```

**Here is my Xib:**  The sheet starts out of the scene's bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `layoutIfNeeded` once before changing the constraint constant. You just added the view in window, so the initial auto layout and your constraint changes happing together in animation. Try this.

```
- (void)showZhePhotoSheetView{
    if (!_sheetIsShowing){
        [[[UIApplication sharedApplication ].delegate window ] addSubview: self ];
        self.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen ].bounds;
        _sheetIsShowing = YES;
        [self layoutIfNeeded];

        [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.3f delay:0.f options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
            self.vesselViewBottomConstraint.constant = 0;
           // [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints ]; // add it or not ,don't like it matters.
            [self layoutIfNeeded];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
    }
}
```